# Representing rational homotopy class by geometric objects

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rational-homotopy-theory

Given a smooth manifold $M$,  we can study its rational homotopy type by looking at differential forms. I am wondering if there is a way to represent each $rational$ homotopy class by geometric objects, like submanifolds in $M$? The famous work of Sacks and Unlenbeck says that one can represent the usual $second$ homotopy group by harmonic map. However, it seems it is not clear how to do with rational homotopy groups. Such a theory might be useful to understand the Bott conjecture stating that a compact nonnegatively curved manifold has only finitely many nonvanishing rational homotopy groups.

Comment: Comments and answers to this old question of mine have lots of good references, some of which may be applicable: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35253/do-free-higher-homotopy-classes-of-compact-riemannian-manifolds-have-preferred-r